# How to remove row from CFLoop query results

Tags: coldfusion, cfquery, cfloop

I'm using loop through a query and joining a table when records exist to join.

Is there a way to then keep the row from returning altogether when there is no record to join on that row?

Edit: I missed an if statement in there. I'm looping through records and checking for a setup option, if that setup options exists in a record and there is no corresponding record in the query "someRecord" those are the records I do not want to return.

```
<cfloop query="myquery">
    <cfif listfindnocase(myquery.setup_option,"required_information")>
        <cfquery name="someRecord" dbtype="query">
            select * from second_table
            where key_id = '#myquery.key_id#'
        </cfquery>
        <cfif someRecord.recordcount eq 0>

        <!--- Need something here to remove this row from returning in the query --->

        </cfif>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to run that query on every iteration of the loop?

Comment: I think you're fixing this problem in the wrong place. Could you could filter these records out during the original query and join it there?

Comment: What row are you talking about? There are no "rows" returned when the query `recordCount` is zero (0). Also, as others have alluded to, running a separate query for each individual record is very inefficient. Is there any reason you cannot use a JOIN instead?

Comment: I agree strongly with @Leigh: This should be done in the DB, if poss. If not poss, you're gonna have to elaborate more on why not.

Comment: I do not mean to run the query on every iteration of the loop.  I added an if statement that should have been in my original post as well as better explanation.

Comment: Why run a query within a loop at all? Databases are much better at manipulating data. There are more elegant and efficient ways of doing this with either an INNER or OUTER join. Also, are you storing lists of values in a single column? If so, do yourself a favor: don't. Databases are designed to manipulate *rows* of information, not lists. Storing lists leads to data integrity and performance issues. [Normalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191178%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) the tables to store the options in rows instead and this task would probably be much easier.

Comment: Do you need to actually remove the row from the query (ie: then use the query elsewhere), or are you simply wanting to skip that row from further processing in your loop? It can be read both ways (although your usage of "return" makes me think you're wanting to modify the query for later reuse?

Comment: Just skip the row from the query

Comment: As Leigh said - using the proper join type will get those records out of the query. In the code above you are showing the wrong query. Paste the query with the actual join statement and we can help.

Comment: @kmorris84 "Just skip the row from the query". OK, you ight want to update your question to actually ask that. Its current wording suggests you want to filter the rows out of the query object, not simply "do nothing" for a given row when iterating over it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, the model answer here is: do not do this in CFML, do it on the DB. CF is for string generation, not data manipulation.

The question is slightly misleading as it initially asks how to remove rows from the query, which - as it turns out - is not the requirement (see comments on the question). I have answered that question further down.

To simply exit an iteration of a loop, use the `<cfcontinue>`. This ends the current iteration of the loop immediately, and returns to the top of the code block and starts the next iteration. Using your own code example:

```
<cfloop query="myquery">
    <cfif listfindnocase(myquery.setup_option,"required_information")>
        <cfquery name="someRecord" dbtype="query">
            select * from second_table
            where key_id = '#myquery.key_id#'
        </cfquery>
        <cfif someRecord.recordcount eq 0>
            <cfcontinue>
        </cfif>
        <!--- handle the rows you *do* want to process here --->
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

However to answer the question of how to remove rows from a query, there's no elegant way of doing it. You have two inelegant options:

```
// pseudocode, for brevity
newQuery = queryNew(oldQuery.columnList)
loop (oldQuery)
    if the row is not wanted
        continue
    /if
    add a row to newQuery
    add the row data to newQuery
/loop
```

Or:

```
listOfRowsToExclude = someMechanismToArriveAtSaidList()
<cfquery name="newQuery" type="query">
    SELECT   *
    FROM     oldQuery
    WHERE    id NOT IN (listOfRowsToExclude)
    ORDER BY [same clause as for oldQuery]
</cfquery>
```

However by far the best advice to be had here is to do your data processing in the DB where it belongs. You should not be putting this sort of logic in a) your CFML app; b) in your view code, which is where I suspect all this is going.

Separate your logic from your display. And separate your data-processing logic from your application logic.

Comment: RE: `listFindNoCase(myquery.setup_option, ..)` Also, just to reiterate, the use of list functions on a query column suggests the db table is not normalized and that is the reason behind the awkward looping. If so, I would strongly suggest restructuring the table. Then you could use a JOIN instead and let the database do what it does best.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than loop through the query to make multiple `SELECT`s (as others have mentioned that it uses unnecessary resources), perhaps try an `IN` clause using `ValueList` to extract a list of IDs:

```
<cfset myqueryIDs = ValueList(myquery.key_id)>
<cfif listfindnocase(myquery.setup_option,"required_information")>
    <cfquery name="allRecords" dbtype="query">
        select * from second_table
        where key_id IN (#myqueryIDs#) <!--- Assuming numeric IDs --->
    </cfquery>
</cfif>
```

Comment: It will not work if `myquery.recordCount` is 0. And looping is still required, because we need to perform `listfindnocase` for the myquery.setup_option for each record.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is something else done after your closing cfif, you should invert your if statement and do this:

```
<cfloop query="myquery">
    <cfquery name="someRecord" dbtype="query">
        select * from second_table
        where key_id = '#session.key_id#'
    </cfquery>

    <cfif someRecord.recordcount neq 0>

      <!--- do what you would do when record count NOT equal to zero --->
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Why are you are running the identical query each time in the loop?  Your comment to the question implied that this was unwise.

Comment: @DanBracuk if I knew the outer query, I would join them, but I don't.  I answered his question in the most direct way possible.

Comment: @DanBracuk It may or may not be the exact same query, I assume he is setting they key_id somewhere else within this loop.

Comment: @AdamCameron that's quite presumptuous.

Comment: Why would you assume that he's resetting a session variable each time through the loop?

Comment: @Adam, it does what he is looking for, by not rendering the row, he is in effect removing it form the results.

Comment: @DanBracuk, else he wouldn't need to re-run the query in each iteration.  His edited question clears it up anyways.

Comment: In the overall scheme of things I consider this to be a bad answer.  I have downvoted accordingly.

Comment: @NeilN: I stand corrected (and will shortly delete my comments to the contrary). I still think the wording of the question is not actually asking a question that this is the solution to, however it does seem it's the OP's intent. That said, see my updated answer which would be my own preference cf your approach.